# MyBatis generator - Generate mapper implementation

Tags: java, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I'm using MyBatis generator and the files created are correct: model class, java mapper, xml mapper. The problem is that the java mapper is just generating the interface, not the implementation.
As far as I see it, it should be easy to generate also the implementation, using the methods in the xml mapper.

Is there any way to generate the implementation to the mapper interface?
Or am I misunderstanding the concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapper Implementation is created by mybatis as proxy class during the application startup. Your mapper xml file corresponding to the interface would be translated to plain java jdbc code and would be implemented in proxy class. And using the interface you access these proxy classes.

Comment: Your answer is good, but it doesn't explain how to use the proxy classes.
It would be something like this:

    RoleExample example = new RoleExample();
    
    RoleMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(RoleMapper.class);
    return mapper.selectByExample(example);